# retorna vacía una petición ajax en jquery

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Estoy realizando una función de realizar compra, en el cual envió los datos del formulario con ajax pero la petición de ajax me retorna vacía  en la consola del navegador

```js
function registar_compra(nombre,cedula){ 
        funcion='registar_compra';
        let total=$('#total').get(0).textContent;
        let productos=recuperarLs();
        let json=JSON.stringify(productos);
        
        
        $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url:'../controlador/controlador-compra.php',
            data:{
                funcion:funcion,
                total:total,
                nombre:nombre,
                cedula:cedula,
                json:json
            },
            success:function(response){
                console.log(response);
            },
            error:function(estado,error){
                console.log(estado);
                console.log(error);
            },
            complete:function(estado){
                console.log(estado);
            }
            
        });
        
    }
```

---

este es fichero del controlador compra el cual realizo transacciones para poder  usar 3 tablas, el primer foreach es un arreglo json que recibo de la función anterior de jquery que adjunte anteriormente

```html
<?php
    include '../modelo/venta.php';
    include_once '../modelo/conexion.php';

    $venta=new ventas();

    session_start();
    $vendedor=$_SESSION['usuario'];

    if($_POST['funcion']=='registrar_compra'){
        $total=$_POST['total'];
        $nombre=$_POST['nombre'];
        $cedula=$_POST['cedula'];
        $productos=json_decode($_POST['json']);
        print_r($productos);
        date_default_timezone_set('America/Guayaquil');
        $fecha=date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

        $venta->crear($nombre,$cedula,$total,$fecha,$vendedor);

        $venta->ultima_venta();

        foreach ($venta->objetos as $objeto) {
            $id_venta=$objeto->ultima_venta;
            echo $id_venta;
        }

        try {
            $db=new conexion();
            $con=$db->pdo;
            $con->beginTransaction();
            foreach ($productos as $prod) {
                $cantidad=$prod->cantidad;
                while ($cantidad!=0) {
                    $sql="SELECT * FROM lote WHERE vencimiento = (SELECT MIN(vencimiento) FROM lote WHERE lote_Id_prod=:id) AND lote_Id_prod=:id";
                    $query=$con->prepare($sql);
                    $query->execute(array(':id'=>$prod->id));
                    $lote=$query->fetchall();
                    foreach ($lote as $lote) {
                        if($cantidad < $lote->stock){
                            $cantidad=0;
                            $con->exec("UPDATE lote SET stock=stock-'$cantidad' WHERE id_lote=:'$lote->id_lote'");
                            $sql="INSERT INTO detalle_venta (det_cantidad,det_vencimiento,Id_det_lote,Id_det_prod,Id_det_prov,Id_det_venta)VALUES()";
                        }
                        if($cantidad == $lote->stock){
                            $con->exec("DELETE FROM lote  WHERE id_lote=:'$lote->id_lote'");
                            $cantidad=0;
                        }
                        if($cantidad > $lote->stock){
                            $con->exec("DELETE FROM lote  WHERE id_lote=:'$lote->id_lote'");
                            $cantidad=$cantidad-$lote->stock;
                        }
                        
                    }
                }
                $subtotal=$prod->cantidad*$prod->precio;
                $con->exec("INSERT INTO venta_producto(cantidad,subtotal,producto_Id_producto,venta_Id_venta)VALUES('$prod->cantidad','$subtotal','$prod->id','$id_venta')");
                $con->commit();
            }

        } catch (Exception $error) {
            //roll se usa para analuar la transaccion tras un error
            $con->rollBack();
            $venta->borrar($id_venta);
            echo $error->getMessage();
        }
    }

?>
```

Comment: Sin poder ver el código php de esa página va a ser difícil adivinar qué pasa. Te recomiendo que pongas todo el código relacionado con tu pregunta

Comment: Este documento no te da ningún error? La consulta sql la realiza correctamente?

Answer (score 0):

Prueba a cambiar el **`success`** por **`.done`**, así:

```
$.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url:'../controlador/controlador-compra.php',
            data:{
                funcion:funcion,
                total:total,
                nombre:nombre,
                cedula:cedula,
                json:json     
        }).done(function(response){
                console.log(response);
         });
```

Si puedes adjuntar el archivo ***controlador-compra.php*** lo puedo mirar, quizás el error se encuentre ahí.